# How to store bigint array in file in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I've a UDF that returns bigint array. I want to store that in a file on Pyspark cluster.

Sample Data -

```py
[
    Row(Id='ABCD505936', array=[0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18]),
    Row(Id='EFGHI155784', array=[1, 2, 4, 10, 16, 22, 27, 32, 36, 38, 39, 40])
]
```

I tried saving it like this -

```
df.write.save("/home/data", format="text", header="true", mode="overwrite")
```

But it throws an error saying -

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o101.save. : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source
>   does not support array data type.;

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: how do you imagine your final output ? can you show us an example ? any constraint you need to respect ?

Comment: Hi @Steven, I just need the array to be stored as is in a text or csv format (if possible). These are actually the fingerprints of chemical structures which I need to read in another program and do comparison. This is my requirement, I hope I'm making sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "array",
    F.col("array").cast("string")
).write.save(
    "/home/data", format="text", header="true", mode="overwrite"
)
```

Comment: Hi @Steven, Thank you it worked! I just changed the format="text" to format="csv".